# How do I set the proper Ruby version for use with my Rails 5 project in Aptana 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, version, aptana, aptana3

I'm usingn Aptana Studio 3 on Mac High Sierra.  I have imported my Rails 5 project and set "Rails" as my project natures in the "Properties" section of my project.  However when editing some Ruby files, Aptana is incorrectly reporting syntax errors on the left side of the editor.  For example, this line

```
creds = PasswordService.find_user(params[:login])&.object
```

is flagged with this error

```
syntax error, unexpected tDOT
```

even though this doesn't raise any errors when I run my project.  I'm wondering if Aptana is not picking up the correct version of Ruby associated with my project but I'm not sure how to check/set that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Aptana, but maybe you want to set your Ruby version too because the safe navigation `&` is a Ruby feature.
In the project directory run `ruby -v` in the console and check the ruby version, it must be higher than 2.3.

If you use a ruby version manager (rbenv or rvm) make sure you configure the right Ruby version for the project.

Comment: I use rvm and confirmed that running "ruby -v" in the console results in "ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17)"

Answer (score 0):

Is `studio3-ruby` the plugin you're using?

If so, I found this open issue that seems related to Ruby 2.0 support:
https://github.com/aptana/studio3-ruby/issues/8

Comment: I"m using Aptana Studio 3 for Mac.  How do I figure out if I'm using the studio3-ruby plugin?  Also, I see the Github issue you listed, but I don't see the resolution or work-around suggestion.